# ¿Por qué no me está detectando la etiqueta de enlace?

Tags: html5, href

Estoy haciendo un login y abajo estoy poniendo el tipico enlace de que si quiere crearse una cuenta que vaya a la pagina de registro, pero es que no me detecta el enlace y no encuentro el error, este es mi código html:

```html
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="Todas las recetas profesionales de los mejores cocineros a tu alcance." />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Recetas,cocina,restaurantes,comida,postres" />
        <meta name="author" content="Mario Ramos García" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/logo.PNG" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css" />
        <title>Cook-It!</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#login-button").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                $('form').fadeOut(500);
                $('.wrapper').addClass('form-success');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid row p-0 m-0">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Bienvenido a Cook-It!</h1>
                    <form class="form" method="POST" action="index.php">
                        <input type="text" name="usuario" value="<?php if(isset($usuario)) echo $usuario; ?>" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus>
                        <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                        <button type="submit" name="login" id="login-button">Iniciar Sesión</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
                <a href="google.es" class="h6">¿No tienes cuenta? Regístrate.</a>
                <ul class="bg-bubbles">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
      </div>
 </body>
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit browsers */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body :-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body ::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body :-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.wrapper {
  background: #50a3a2;
  background: linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 50%;*/
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 400px;*/
  height: 100%;
  /*margin-top: -200px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper.form-success .container h1 {
    transform: translateY(85px);
}
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 80px 0;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-     put;
  font-weight: 200;
}
form {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
form input {
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
  font-weight: 300;
}
form input:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
form input:focus {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  color: #53e3a6;
}
form button {
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #53e3a6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;

}
form button:hover {
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
}
.bg-bubbles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.bg-bubbles li {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  bottom: -160px;
  animation: square 25s infinite; 
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 10%;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 17s;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 25%;
  animation-delay: 4s;

}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation-duration: 22s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 70%;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 80%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 32%;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  animation-delay: 7s;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 55%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-duration: 40s;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(9) {
  left: 25%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 40s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(10) {
  left: 90%;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  animation-delay: 11s;        
}
@keyframes square {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
  }
}
@keyframes square {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida te invito a leer **[ask]**

Comment: intentastes hacere `<a href="http://google.es">`

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, es rarísimo que no me lo esté detectando

Comment: a mi me funciona tu link, no me envia a google pero si me redirige probaste con la propiedad target="_blank"

Comment: creo que he encontrado el error, puede ser que esté en mi CSS, porque he quitado el linkeado al archivo de estilos y si me funciona, adjunto codigo css arriba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en tu CSS:

```
.bg-bubbles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Al poner z-index a 1, queda por encima del enlace. Cuando hacés click donde ves el enlace, en realidad, estás haciendo click sobre bg-bubbles. Cambiá los z-index y listo. Por ejemplo:

```
<a href="google.es" class="h6" style="
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
">¿No tienes cuenta? Regístrate.</a>
```

Comment: Estoy probando a cambiarlos pero por mucho que cambie el z-index sigue sin poder utilizarse, si les pongo z-index: -1 a los bubbles no se ven y si que funciona el enlace, como lo podría soolucionar?

Comment: El z-index únicamente se aplica a los elementos que tienen una posición. Asigná las propiedad position a relative y ahí el enlace va a hacer caso de z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que le estás pasando mal el atributo a la etiqueta [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a).

```
<a href="google.es" class="h6">¿No tienes cuenta? Regístrate.</a>
```

Entonces `href="google.es"` deberías pasarle el `http://` al principio, quedando asi: `href="http://google.es"`, si lo que querés es cambiar de archivo (localmente), tenés que pasarle la ruta, por ejemplo:

```
<a href="registrate.html" class="h6">¿No tienes cuenta? Regístrate.</a>
```